# Running ASP.NET Core exe from MacOS Finder produces error: "The WebRootPath was not found"

Tags: asp.net-core

I have published an ASP.NET Core app for MacOS.  If I run it from the terminal (./BlazorApp1) it works fine.  But if I try to run the exe from Finder I always get this error message:

*The WebRootPath was not found: /Users/scott/wwwroot. Static files may be unavailable*

Is it possible to run the exe produced from Finder?

---

Publish settings:

Configuration: Release

Target Framework: net8.0

Deployment Mode: Self-Contained

Target Runtime: osx-arm64

Options:

Enable ReadyToRun compilation

Produce single file

Comment: The path `/Users/scott/wwwroot` is suspicious. It means you deployed the application to your user directory. What does your code actually look like? How did you publish  the web app and did you remember to create `wwwroot` as well? `wwwroot` is where the static files (css js, images) requested by the browser are stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the issue by using below settings in MacOS.

```
// For OSX
if (System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.OSX))
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    { 
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "wwwroot")), RequestPath = "" });
    }
// For Windows
else {
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I am going to add some notes for future reference.

If you are packaging up the site as a single executable there is a slight change.  FileProvider must get its path from AppContext.BaseDirectory.

There is at least one trade-off I have seen.  IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath will now always be null, so code like:

Env.WebRootPath + "/data/sample.json"

would need to be:

Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(AppContext.BaseDirectory)!, "wwwroot") + "/data/sampledata.json"

Comment: The app.UseStaticFiles(); does work fine on a Mac while developing, so there are code execution differences that need to be tested when running only on a Mac after bundling for release.  This is a consideration to take if it is worth it rather than just running from the terminal and living with the limitation.